# Powershell to copy user "member-of" groups to a security group

Tags: powershell

I was curious if it's possible to copy "member-of" groups from a user to a security group?

Comment: I don't know. What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Yes it is possible.

You should show some effort and try to solve it yourself and come back with a more specific question if you get stuck.